# where is the option of setting longer curl argument list threshold to avoid "Argument list too long" error

Tags: linux, curl

The shell code is:
`#!/bin/sh
body="............a lot of thing................";
curl -Ss -d"${body}" "xx.xx.com"`

But it couldn't be ran and sent via curl,the error is:
/usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long

It might be the $body is too long.I wonder are there any options to set curl to send longer post?

Answer (score 28):

Store your body data in a file. and use

```
  curl -d @<filename>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to shut up if I stored it in a file.

```
curl -o fn URLETC
```

Comment: doesn't change anything for me.